# HTML5 video player plays only audio and no video for mkv file

Tags: html5-video, mkv

I am trying to play an mkv video in HTML5 video player. When i play the video only audio gets played and no video. Following is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <body> 
    <video width="500" controls>
      <source src="SampleVideo.mkv">
    </video>
  </body> 
</html>
```

I am using chrome browser (version 74.0.3729.169).
I know that HTML5 only supports MP4, WebM, and Ogg formats but is their any way to play MKV files properly? Any help on this would really be appreciated.

Comment: you'll need to transcode your mkv to mp4/webm for reliable playback. Chrome does have some support for mkv, but you'll want to add `type='video/x-matroska; codecs="theora, vorbis"'` after the src to give it more of a hint

Comment: I did try adding type='video/x-matroska; codecs="theora, vorbis"' after src but it didn't work. Now video is not playing at all.